# How do I quit and copy the map?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My sister and I made a really cool house. She wanted to download the world so she could have it too. Problem is, in 0.7.3 it just say "quit to menu" or whatever. How do you quit and copy the world? Where did the menu option go to copy a multiplayer world?

Comment: What do you mean by "in 7.3" Minecraft is at version 1.6.2. Or is this about some console or mobile version?

Comment: does she want the house, or how the world looks?

Comment: Seeds are the world as it is generated when you FIRST enter it, they do not carry any changed made by a player to said world.

Comment: No. I meant for pocket edition. It used to say quit and copy map. Hit that button and you get the seed AND structures made by players

Comment: Try ```/seed```.

Comment: They're playing PE.